# How are patriotic songs used in US churches?

Tags: worship, religious-practice, music, politics, united-states

A comical blog mentioned “[patriotic worship](http://everydayimpastoring.tumblr.com/post/26022955004/me-sitting-in-fourth-of-july-patriotic-worship)”. It is also hinted at in [this article](http://www.churchleaders.com/worship/worship-articles/152232-disturbed-on-the-fourth-of-july.html) and in [this article](http://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/trevinwax/2014/07/02/why-younger-evangelicals-may-feel-uneasy-in-a-patriotic-church-service/) where it is made clear that patriotic songs such as the ones [listed here](http://www.sonserver.com/america/songs-usa.htm) are sung and they are considered suitable for worship by some groups. It is apparent that within the USA patriotism and Christianity are sometimes conflated. As you can imagine, it is quite difficult to search for information regarding worship and patriotism, especially in connection with the United States. I would like to know how prevalent the singing of patriotic songs is, which denominations are the most likely to use them and does their use peak around patriotic festivals such as Independence Day and Memorial Day?

Comment: The provided link does not go to a specific post, and I'm having difficulty figuring out to which specific post, on that page, you are referring.

Comment: This is a very interesting question on a topic that I have been trying to get the community here to address, but they are reluctant, hence I'm reading this post in the close review queue right now. I think this question supports my case made in this meta post: [How should we handle questions about Christian culture?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1841) I am *not* going to vote to close.

Comment: Sorry, having never heard of this, I need more information to understand what it is and proof that it's a Christian (the religion) practice.

Comment: Related: http://everydayimpastoring.tumblr.com/day/2014/08/21

Comment: @TheFreemason It's on everydayiampastoring which is about life as a member of the clergy/church life. I'd say it's generally quite liberal/high church but it is pretty mainstream. The fact it is there tells me that it is an ongoing Christian practice. It is like a Dave Walker cartoon, you can be certain that it is connected to church life.

Comment: I think this would be more clearly ontopic if it focused on the origin and use of the phrase.

Comment: I would have thought that concentrating on origin and use of phrase would probably push it more towards being migrated to English Language & Usage.

Comment: @Flimzy It might be satire, but the conflation of US patriotism and Christianity is real. I see it daily. As the comment above yours notes, this is real. Your attitude is dismissive likely because you are unfamiliar with this.

Comment: @Flimzy Are questions on Christian practice regarded as off topic? If I asked a question like "Which UK denominations celebrate Candlemass?" would that be off-topic? I fail to see how this question is functionally different.

Comment: I think the difference is that you could show with certainty that some UK denominations celebrate Candlemass. All we have to go on here is a comic.

Comment: @TRiG I've been to a church in my area where the American flag has a permanent home next to the alter. The Sunday near Independence Day is not the only one where patriotism is the focus of the sermon. There's also Memorial Day and Veteran's Day. Just one more needed in winter and all four seasons are covered. Coincidentally, someone brought suit against this Church for political campaigning (which would be legal if they forgo their tax free status). My Grandfather, not a church goer, often lamented that the Church didn't do enough in telling its members how to vote. Strange stuff.

Comment: This question and a broader issue are being discussed on the meta site: [Are questions on Christian practices off-topic (in light of the patriotic worship question)?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4124)

Comment: @flimzy thanks - I only gave a passing familiarity with US holidays.

Comment: I only **have** a passing familiarity

Answer (score 3):

In the LDS church in the US it is common to sing patriotic songs around Independence Day and sometimes Memorial Day and Veteran's Day too (though I think that's more rare). It is very unusual to hear them sung at church any other time.

[Official guidance](https://www.lds.org/music/resources/using-the-hymnbook?lang=eng) on the matter:

> **National Anthems**
>
> A few patriotic songs have been included in the hymnbook; with
>   priesthood approval, local national anthems may be added. Members may
>   stand for national anthems in Church meetings according to local
>   custom and priesthood direction.

The patriotic songs in the hymnbook include [America the Beautiful](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/america-the-beautiful?lang=eng), [My Country, 'Tis of Thee](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/my-country-tis-of-thee?lang=eng), [The Star-Spangled Banner](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/the-star-spangled-banner?lang=eng), and strangely enough [God Save the King](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/god-save-the-king?lang=eng).

Mormons have a unique feeling of US patriotism because they believe God founded the country to provide a free place for him to restore his church (the LDS church).

> Our Father in Heaven planned the coming forth of the Founding Fathers and their form of government as the necessary great prologue leading to the restoration of the gospel. Recall what our Savior Jesus Christ said nearly two thousand years ago when He visited this promised land: “For it is wisdom in the Father that they should be established in this land, and be set up as a free people by the power of the Father, that these things might come forth” [(3 Ne. 21:4)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/21.4?lang=eng#3). America, the land of liberty, was to be the Lord’s latter-day base of operations for His restored church. - [Ezra Taft Benson](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1987/10/our-divine-constitution?lang=eng)

You can also read [God's Hand in the Founding of America](https://www.lds.org/new-era/1976/07/gods-hand-in-the-founding-of-america?lang=eng).