# Do Mormons in European countries also sing patriotic American songs?

Tags: lds, religious-practice, music, europe

The answer to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34182/how-are-patriotic-songs-used-in-us-churches) says about the hymnbook used by the LDS church in USA that:

> The patriotic songs in the hymnbook include America the Beautiful, My
>   Country, 'Tis of Thee, The Star-Spangled Banner, and strangely enough
>   God Save the King.
>
> Mormons have a unique feeling of US patriotism because they believe
>   God founded the country to provide a free place for him to restore his
>   church (the LDS church).

In those European countries, where English is not the native language (such as Germany and Russia), do Mormons sing translated versions of these American patriotic songs?

Or do they perhaps use their own local patriotic songs, or no patriotic songs at all?

Comment: I am a member in the USA so I don't have personal experience with this, but I would be very surprised if other countries sang American patriotic songs (either translated or still in English).   Although Mormons do have a unique respect for the USA as indicated in the linked question, that doesn't translate into required loyalty to the USA for those who wouldn't already have such loyalty.

Comment: In Canada all the hymn books have "Oh Canada" in them.

Comment: Sometimes LDS leaders in Britain will order the singing of *Jerusalem* by William Blake. It is a bit off-message with some American Mormons, as it draws on the legend of Christ's supposed visit to England with his "uncle", Joseph of Arimathea - *And did those feet in ancient time, walk upon England's pastures green...*, *And did the countenance divine, shine forth upon those clouded hills?* - All very disconcerting stuff for anyone brought up on the Book of Mormon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Latter-day Saints in other countries do not typically sing United States patriotic songs.

The full LDS hymnbook is currently published in [38 languages](http://singpraises.net/). The English hymnbook has 341 hymns, including four patriotic songs:

- America the Beautiful (USA)
- My Country, ’Tis of Thee (USA)
- The Star-Spangled Banner (USA)
- God Save the King (United Kingdom)

For a short time, the Church also published [national anthem inserts](http://singpraises.net/collection/national-anthem-inserts?lang=eng) for the English hymnbook, labeled as hymn 342:

- O Canada (Canada)
- Advance Australia Fair (Australia)
- God Defend New Zealand (New Zealand)

Hymnbooks in other languages have around 200 hymns from the current English hymnbook, plus a few additional hymns that are optionally chosen by the translators. None of them have United States patriotic songs; however, a few have local patriotic songs:

- [Finnish](http://singpraises.net/collection/hymns?lang=fin): "Finlandia-hymni" (Finlandia) and "Siunaa ja varjele meitä" (Bless and Protect Us)
- [Italian](http://singpraises.net/collection/hymns?lang=ita): "Va, pensiero sull’ali dorate" (Fly, Thought, on Wings of Gold / Chorus of the Hebrew Slaves, from an opera by Verdi)
- [Norwegian](http://singpraises.net/collection/hymns?lang=nor): "Gud signe vårt dyre fedreland" (God Bless Our Precious Homeland)
- [Samoan](http://singpraises.net/collection/hymns?lang=smo): "Lo Matou Atua e, Matou te Fa‘afetai" (Our God, We Raise to Thee, a generic patriotic song not specifically Samoan)
- [Thai](http://singpraises.net/collection/hymns?lang=tha): "เพลงชาติ" (Thai National Anthem) and "สรรเสริญพระบารมี" (Praise to the King / The King’s Anthem)

At the back of the English hymnbook, this guidance is given:

> A few patriotic songs have been included in the hymnbook; with priesthood approval, local national anthems may be added. Members may stand for national anthems in Church meetings according to local custom and priesthood direction (["Using the Hymnbook,"](https://www.lds.org/music/resources/using-the-hymnbook?lang=eng) *Hymns,* 381).

Local leaders are able to decide which anthems or patriotic songs are appropriate for Church meetings where they live.

Although Latter-day Saints around the world hold the United States in high esteem – that the United States was [uniquely set apart](http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/United_States_of_America) for the latter-day restoration of the gospel, and that the New Jerusalem will be built [on the American continent](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/a-of-f/1?verse=10&lang=eng#10) – they are encouraged to [honor the law](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/a-of-f/1?verse=12&lang=eng#12) and be actively involved in strengthening their community wherever they live.

Comment: If interested anyone can see the hymns each language has by going to https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns?lang=eng&_r=1 and selecting a language

Comment: As the present monarch of the United Kingdom is female, and has been on the throne more than  65 years (the longest reign of any British monarch), it does seem quite remarkable that the LDS church has still not got round to changing the hymn to "God Save the Queen".

Comment: @WS2, that seems a good point, but the anthem was originally - and is technically - "God Save the King," the monarchial reference changing depending on who's on the throne.  The better question is why it wasn't changed when the book was redesigned in 1985?  not earlier is due to cost (long story), and  I get it that it's not worth changing it now since the long-lived and long-loved Elizabeth will eventually lose to the odds and England will likely have a king for quite a long time... but 20+ years ago?  It should have been changed then when the cost was expensed.

Comment: Having been a missionary to Finland, the hymnal is "Suomen Lauluja."  "[Finlandia-hymni](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/finlandia-hymn?lang=fin)" is a hymn/composition dear to the hearts of the Finns.  Written by Jean Sibelius, "[Finlandia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finlandia)" (the music of which is used for the English LDS hymn "Be Still, My Soul"), speaks powerfully to the beauty of the nation and soul of its people.